# refer to a variable using multiple names in C

Tags: c, variables

Is it possible to refer to a variable using multiple names in C ? I know this could be done via pointers but is it possible without using pointers. Just like we use 'typedef' for multiple naming of data type, similar for Variables

I have a constant named FILTER_PROC_LOAD_INTERNSITY, How to refer to it using simple name like 'var1'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you may want to use macros?

```
#define var1 FILTER_PROC_LOAD_INTERNSITY
```

but the question is: why?
one "thing" one responsibility. You do not want to baffle the reader of your code. The name of the Variable seems to be wrong in the first place, if you have the need to rename the name.

Edith:

what my problem with readability is expressed in this example

```
char *very_ugly_variable_name;
#define beautifulVariableName very_ugly_variable_name

void unmaintainable_old_function() {
   print(very_ugly_variable_name);
}

void myOtherNewFunction() {
   print(beautifulVariableName);
}
```

you do not grok in a moment, that very_ugly_variable_name and beautifulVariableName are the exact same (in namescope and in memory).

Comment: Ohh yes thanks. I forgot about macros. I am going to put comments in code to make it more readable. a short name is convenient as I have to use it multiple times. 'var1' is just for illustration purpose.

Comment: why is a valid counter question, make the code readable by renaming var1 into something readable.

Comment: It's unwise to use a short name for convenience at the expense of readibility. You're not repeatedly typing it into a command prompt, you're writing it just a few times in your source code, and that source code may be repeatedly read.

Answer (score 1):

The C language does not seem to have references (to *alias* your variable) but you can use a pointer to that end: `yourtype* var1 = &FILTER_PROC_LOAD_INTERNSITY` and then use `*var1` to get the value of your constant. But this doesn't look like a good idea - symbolic names in programs are much easier to read and understand.